# Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, email

### Details

- I am running a PHP script on my local Windows 7 machine using **php.exe**
- I want to trigger an email at the end of my script, but I couldn't get it to send an email.

Mail

`mail('email@gmail.com', '$title' , '$data' );`

This is what I've in my **php.ini**

```
[mail function]

SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 25
username = email@gmail.com
password = *****
sendmail_from = email@gmail.com
```

I still can't send out any mail. I keep getting :

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l49sm2288391qgd.21 - gsmtp

Please kindly advise - if I did anything wrong.

Feel free to give me any suggestions.

Thank-you for your time !

Comment: Make life easy. Don't use `mail()`, use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` is one of those PHP functions that should have never become part of PHP code, because it's simply poorly implemented and very plain. It just does not support TLS so use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or similar package instead

Comment: It made sense at the time, and it still makes some sense for isolated installations where you have control over everything and just want to send some damn local mail.

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP server is requiring TLS, but `mail` doesn't support that. It's a very basic function.

You should use an industrial-strength SMTP library instead if you want to send mail.